# Unable to fetch VM instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an "owner" account on the Google Cloud Platform for my company. Normally I am able to go to "Compute Engine" > "VM instances" and view all of our virtual machines. However, most of the time it now gives me an error displaying "You do not have permission to fetch the requested resource." This is also occurring for another owner on the platform. Every once in awhile I am able to see the instances and access them, but it is rare.

Is there a reason that this would happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since issue seems to be sporadic, when it does occur again, please use incognito mode on your browser and try to log in again. If issue persists, then I would create open an internal issue [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for further investigation.